# is this intreactive plot/web app created only with svelte?

Tags: web-applications, svelte

Here's a nice [epidemic calculator](https://gabgoh.github.io/COVID/index.html)

I want to know how it was created.

I know it's possible to do something similar with python/dash.

Looking at the source code, it might have been created with [svelte](https://svelte.dev/).

Is there anything else? Or is svelte enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are credits for this app, why don't you ask the author ?

But yes, it's a Svelte APP, the sources are here : https://github.com/gabgoh/epcalc

Comment: Nice of you to assume that I didn't ask him. I did, got no reply. Many thanks